# Zoom into a point math

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have some confusion of how to implement zoom in point in HTML canvas. I have read all the other posts here about it, but there is an issue that is still not clear to me.

So, I fully understand the concept of zooming into point - first translate the desired zooming center to the origin, scale in/out, translate back. So if I wish to zoom around point `p1` by factor `k1` and then again around point `p2` by factor `k2`, I will first translate to origin with transformation `T1 = T(-p1.x, -p1.y)`, zoom with `S1(k1)` by factor `k1` and translate back with `T1' = T(p1.x, p1.y)`.

Then again will do the same around `p2`: translate to origin with `T2 = T(-p2.x, -p2.y)`, zoom with `S2(k2)` by factor `k2` and translate back with `T2' = T(p2.x, p2.y)`. So those two zoom actions will transform a given point `q` to `q'` with the following:

```
q' = (T2' * S2 * T2) * (T1' * S1 * T1) * q
```

Now suppose I want to implement it with HTML canvas. I would expect that the following lines will accomplish it:

```
// First zoom around p1
context.translate(-p1.x, -p1.y); // T1 - translate to origin
context.scale(k1,k1); // S1 - scale
context.translate(p1.x, p1.y); // T1' - translate back

// Then zoom around p2
context.translate(-p2.x, -p2.y); // T2 - translate to origin
context.scale(k2,k2); // S2 - scale
context.translate(p2.x, p2.y); // T2' - translate back
```

However, since the HTML canvas post-multiply transformations, this piece of code will be interpreted as the following:

```
q' = (T1 * S1 * T1') * (T2 * S2 * T2') * q
```

This obviously won't yield what I want - the multiplication order is not as I wanted.

Why is it like that? What intuition I'm missing? My intuition for when I read this piece of code top to bottom is that the transformations should be pre-multiplied.

Thanks!

Comment: This post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339747/zoom-and-pan-in-animated-html5-canvas/27340533#27340533

Comment: "the multiplication order is not as I wanted", with multiplication, order doesn't matter.

Comment: using save() and restore() is a much simpler way of using different transforms.

Comment: @K3N : unfortunately for us all, no, matrix multiplication isn't commutative.

Comment: @GameAlchemist a (transformation) matrix involves addition as well. I was nevertheless referring to the formula in the question which only do multiplications so OP didn't have to waste time experiment changing order around.

Comment: A transformation matrix is a matrix. With matrix multiplication, order does matter. And the formula corresponding to the code should read q' = (T2' * S2 * T2) * (T1' * S1 * T1) * q